# is it possible to serialize hibernate EntitiyManagerFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a project that uses hibernate and the startup time is very long, I was wondering if it is possible to serialize the EntitiyManagerFactory and thus only first startup would be slow.

Comment: The answer is: Does it implement `Serializable`?

Comment: You might want to do some more research on why it's slow.

Comment: From Gaving KING : `The "serialized" SessionFactory is in fact just a name; it doesn't serialize the whole state. You need to rebuild the factory if you restart.` Source : https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HB-178?focusedCommentId=10677&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-10677"

Answer (score 2):

It *can* be serialized in hibernate (not necessarily the case in other JPA implementations), because the hibernate internal interface extends `Serializable`. But this is for internal use, probably by the application server to be able to passivate it somehow.

Your problem lies somewhere else and should not be solved by serializing the entity manager factory. Usually on startup it creates a connection pool and fills it with fresh database connections. And you can't serialize these connections, so a whole slew of new problems will appear if you go that way.

Instead, make sure the database is responding timely (if not - it is slowing the filling of the pool), and whether your startup is *really* that slow. 30 seconds is *not* slow, 5 minutes might be slow, depending on the size of the appplication.